# SQL EXECUTE FUNCTION access error?

Tags: sql, teradata

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3523 : 42000] The user does not have EXECUTE FUNCTION access to syslib.udf_IsDecimal. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.112
```

Is there a workaround for this? How would I get access to syslib.udf_IsDecimal?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (SQL is a language)

Comment: please include the appropriate tag in your questions (I've already tagged this one)

Comment: you don't have rights to the function -- you need an adminstrator (dba) to give you rights.

Comment: Ask your DBA to GRANT you the necessary right. As this is probably a function to check if a string can be casted to a numeric value, you might also ry a `TO_NUMBER(string)` which will simply return a `NULL` instead of an error. Btw, TD15.10 supports a nice `TRYCAST` function...